# Deep linking with Brnach.IO with sendGrid integration issue as passing params is undefined while opening link from mail using React native

Tags: react-native, sendgrid, deep-linking, branch.io

**Goal**

I am sending email with deep linking implementation with Branch.IO with sendGrid integration. While user click on link my react native app open in phone and redirect me to screen based on query params in url which i have provided during create link in API.

**Problem**

I am able to open app from link but query params i have provide in link is display as blank. so i am not able to open screen where i want to redirect to user in app.

```
branch.subscribe(({ params, error, uri }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Error from Branch: ' + error)
    return
  }
  console.log("params :: ", params);
  if(params.reset) {
    // Redirect user to reset password screen
    console.log("params.reset :: " + params.reset);
    Actions.resetpassword({resetToken: params.reset});
  } else if(params.verify) {
    // Verify signup user
    axios.post('http://localhost:3030/authmanagement', {
        "action":"verifySignupLong",
        "value": params.verify
      }).then(response => {
          Actions.login({isVerifySuccess: true});
      }, error => {
        Actions.login();
      });
  }
});
```

I have write this code as suggest Branch.IO documentation. In params i have send reset and verify token which i got as blank string.

**Information**

This code is working without integration with sendGrid in deep linking. But for mailing tracking i used sendGrid. So when i try to email with sendGrid it will create problem.

I have setup Link Branding in SendGrid account and also add CNAME in my domain as given in instruction of sendGrid integration for deep linking.

I have check mailed link in [Redirect Detective portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBHPT.png)

I have verified link and it will generate valid url with params. please look into below image for more clarification

[image: Image for Redirect Detective]

Answer (score 0):

Jackie from Branch here.

Based on your redirect link, there seems to be an issue with the SendGrid integration. Could you make sure your integration is properly set up by following the instructions [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/emails/sendgrid/#setup)?

For some context, this is what a link should look like within your email template: `http://example.com/?foo=bar`

When a user clicks your link in the email, Branch processes the link and converts it to something like this:

```
https://vza3.app.link/3p?%243p=e_xx&%24original_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Ffoo%3Dbar

(Where vza3.app.link is your Branch domain.)
```

Also, in order for SendGrid to know that the email link should deep-link and open the app, add universal="true" to the HTML, like so:

```
<a href="http://example.com" universal="true">Link to your app!</a>
```

If you continue to experience issues with passing deep link data via SendGrid email tracking, please reach out to us directly at integrations@branch.io with your Branch key and the link(s) you're using.

Comment: on branch io instruction you provide setup for iOS but what about android app configuration? Is there need to do something with react native app with android device?

Comment: We have an integration guide for React Native app on Android as well: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/#android

Comment: I have follow this step which is working fine with normal email sending for reset password. But I am trying to achieve with SendGrid mail service provider. In sendGrid is change url of tracking purpose. that's why app is not opened with sendGrid link. I have got success without sendGrid integration. But I faced the problem with sending mail via sendGrid mail service.

Comment: @JaydipsinhVaghela I know this was a long time ago but just checking if you ever able to resolve this. Thanks!